# Magento 2 : In custom login extension Default welcome message not changed

Tags: magento2, login, customer-name, custom-extension

I am working with custom extension.

When I login with custom extension login page I am not getting customer name in the top right side instead of default welcome message.

[image]

I want name of customer who is login here as in default it is coming.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you override header.phtml file?

Comment: @RohanHapani yes I override authorization.phtml.

Comment: Please upload that file code.